# Get latest record (detail) from file data while parsing in Perl

Tags: perl

I have alarm data for a Node, which is stored in a file.

Below is the file content:

```
Priority : LOW
Node : NR001
Problem : FREQUENT Problem
eventTime : 2020-09-08T14:30:45
State : ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED
Id : 1071
Number : 1071
ceaseTime : null
ackTime : null
additionalInformation : Object:XYZ=NULL#Frequent_Limit:3#Filter_Time:1
insertTime : 2020-09-08T14:30:45
eventId : 118382
lastUpdated : 2020-09-08T14:30:45

Priority : LOW
Node : NR001
Problem : FREQUENT Problem
eventTime : 2020-09-08T14:30:45
State : ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED
Id : 1071
Number : 1071
ceaseTime : null
ackTime : null
additionalInformation : Object:XYZ=NULL#Frequent_Limit:3#Filter_Time:1
insertTime : 2020-09-08T14:30:45
eventId : 118382
lastUpdated : 2020-09-08T14:32:46

Priority : CLEARED
Node : NR001
Problem : FREQUENT Problem
eventTime : 2020-09-08T14:30:45
State : CLEARED_UNACKNOWLEDGED
Id : 1071
Number : 1071
ceaseTime : 2020-09-08T14:32:46
ackTime : null
additionalInformation : Object:XYZ=NULL#Frequent_Limit:3#Filter_Time:1
insertTime : 2020-09-08T14:30:45
eventId : 118382
lastUpdated : 2020-09-08T14:32:46
```

This data belongs to one alarm, you can see for all the `eventId` the value is `118382`.

If I have multiple alarms, for each of the alarm we will be having different `eventId` numbers. (Here in above example I have only one alarm detail.)

Above data shows what all operations has been performed to an alarm which has eventId = 118382 on 2020-09-08.

What I need to pick from this alarm data with the latest `lastUpated` time for each alarm.

Here is my code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

$/ = "";
my %data;

while(<DATA>) {
    my $rec = { split /\n| : /, $_ };
    $data{$rec->{eventId}} = $rec;
}
print Dumper \%data;

my $limit = "NA";

print "eventId, priority, lastUpdated, limit\n";

foreach my $e_id ( keys %data){
    
    ($limit = $1 ) if( $data{$e_id}{'additionalInformation'} =~ /Frequent_Limit:(\d+)/);
    
    print "$e_id, $data{$e_id}{'Priority'}, $data{$e_id}{'lastUpdated'}, $limit\n";
}
```

My script is picking the last record with respect to particular key. But how can I fetch data based on `lastUpdated` date for a particular eventId.

Also, if I have same value for `lastUpdated` date for a single `eventId`, it should fetch the one which has Priority **CLEARED**.

Here the output should be:

```
eventId, priority, lastUpdated, limit
118382,CLEARED,2020-09-09T14:34:13, 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your records are separated by blank lines, just read chunks separated by blank lines. "Paragraph mode" (`$/ = "";`) makes this trivial.

```perl
my %selected;
{
   local $/ = "";
   while ( my $row = <> ) {
      my %row =
         map { split / : /, $_, 2 }
            split /\n/, $row;

      my $id = $row{eventId};
      $selected{$id} = \%row
         if !$selected{$id}
         || $row{lastUpdated} gt $selected{$id}{lastUpdated}
         || $row{lastUpdated} eq $selected{$id}{lastUpdated} && $row{Priority} eq 'CLEARED';
   }
}

for my $eventId (keys(%selected)) {
   my $row = $selected{$eventId};
   my %addi =
      map { split /:/, $_, 2 }
         split /\#/, $row->{additionalInformation};

   say
      join ",",
         $row->{eventId},
         $row->{Priority},
         $row->{lastUpdated},
         $addi{Frequent_Limit};
}
```

You can speed things up by exiting the loop sooner by making assumptions about the data.

Comment: Thank you. This works fine when I have single set of data. What If I have multiple set of alarms which have different `eventId`s? How do I iterate? I mean how do I have outerloop?

Comment: Ah yes. Because at the end I need to write these data into csv file. So as mentioned, for single `eventId` single record.

Comment: Yes, in question I have mentioned example is for one record. But I also mentioned _If I have multiple alarms, for each of the alarm we will be having different `eventId` numbers_. So looking a logic to work for different eventIds. Will it be possible to do the same using the above solution?

Comment: When I was testing, I have interchanged the input records. Even the data for particular `eventId` is interchanged, it should always take out the data which has _latest_ date in _lastUpdated_ field. Since we are not doing this check in the script, it is  always giving us the last record for the particular `eventId` which is not correct.

Comment: thank you. But when I added one more set of data in the beginning of ___DATA__ _with `lastupdated : 2020-09-09T14:34:13` for `eventId : 118382` with CLEARED priority, it should suppose to show this value, but unfortunately its not.

Comment: I cannot see any typo in your code other than semi-colon missing in line `my $id = $row{eventId}`. But was thinking while storing the information into `%selected` hash its not getting stored based on `lastUpdated`.

Comment: theoretically, if particular `eventId` have latest date in `lastUpdated` field and if `CLEARED` Priority exists, then this date needs to be considered. Else if `CLEARED` Priority doesn't exists for particular `eventId` then it should consider the one has latest date in `lastUpdated` field.

Answer (score -1):

Please investigate following demo code for compliance with your problem

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $eventId = shift || '118382';

my %last_event;
my @fields  = qw/eventId Priority lastUpdated limit/;
my @records = do { local $/ = "", <DATA> };

for my $record ( @records ) {
    my %event = ( $record =~ /^(.*?) : (.*)/mg );
    next unless defined $event{eventId};
    $event{limit} = $1 if $event{additionalInformation} =~ /Frequent_Limit:(\d+)/;
    $last_event{$event{eventId}} = \%event;
}

say join ',', @fields;
say join ',', @{$last_event{$eventId}}{@fields};

__DATA__
Priority : LOW
Node : NR001
Problem : FREQUENT Problem
eventTime : 2020-09-08T14:30:45
State : ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED
Id : 1071
Number : 1071
ceaseTime : null
ackTime : null
additionalInformation : Object:XYZ=NULL#Frequent_Limit:3#Filter_Time:1
insertTime : 2020-09-08T14:30:45
eventId : 118382
lastUpdated : 2020-09-08T14:30:45

Priority : LOW
Node : NR001
Problem : FREQUENT Problem
eventTime : 2020-09-08T14:30:45
State : ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED
Id : 1071
Number : 1071
ceaseTime : null
ackTime : null
additionalInformation : Object:XYZ=NULL#Frequent_Limit:3#Filter_Time:1
insertTime : 2020-09-08T14:30:45
eventId : 118382
lastUpdated : 2020-09-08T14:32:46

Priority : CLEARED
Node : NR001
Problem : FREQUENT Problem
eventTime : 2020-09-08T14:30:45
State : CLEARED_UNACKNOWLEDGED
Id : 1071
Number : 1071
ceaseTime : 2020-09-08T14:32:46
ackTime : null
additionalInformation : Object:XYZ=NULL#Frequent_Limit:3#Filter_Time:1
insertTime : 2020-09-08T14:30:45
eventId : 118382
lastUpdated : 2020-09-08T14:32:46
```

Output

```
eventId,Priority,lastUpdated,limit
118382,CLEARED,2020-09-08T14:32:46,3
```

Comment: @ikegami -- Are you stating that OP is not smart enough to pick from hash value based on **eventId** key? Ok, I modified the code for such situation.

Comment: Nope. And I'm tired of holding your hand.

Comment: @ikegami - when I look at some of your code all I think 'Why this guy does it so over complicated?"

Comment: Cause mine does what the OP asks and yours doesn't. The only real difference between my code and your copy is the bit that's missing. (That, and I used *simpler* expressions than yours, such as a simple split on a constant string rather than a heavier regex match.)