# Pick a record from file based on last updated date for a particular event

Tags: perl

I have list alarm data, where each alarm will be identified with unique key called `eventId`.

For each of the unique `eventId` I should pick the latest operation performed on the alarm.

Latest action performed can be identified by looking into the `lastUpdated` field of the alarm.

Here in below example, I have two alarms data with `eventId` 1001 and 1002, and list operations performed on those particular alarms.

Below is the code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

no warnings 'uninitialized';

use Data::Dumper;
use feature 'say';

my %selected;
{
   local $/ = "";
   while ( my $row = <DATA> ) {
      
      next if ($row =~ /Total number of Alarm/);
      
      my %row =
         map { split / : /, $_, 2 }
            split /\n/, $row;

      my $id = $row{eventId};
      $selected{$id} = \%row
         if $row gt $selected{lastUpdated}
         || $row eq $selected{lastUpdated} && $row{Severity} eq 'CLEARED';
   }
}

say "EventID,Node,Severity,State,LastUpdate";

foreach my $key (keys %selected){
    my $e_id = $selected{$key};
    say "$e_id->{eventId},$e_id->{Node},$e_id->{Severity},$e_id->{State},$e_id->{lastUpdated}";
}

__DATA__
Severity : HIGH
Node : N01
eventId : 1001
State : ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED
lastUpdated : 2020-09-30T12:30:32

Severity : HIGH
Node : N01
eventId : 1001
State : ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED
lastUpdated : 2020-09-30T12:35:33

Severity : CLEARED
Node : N01
eventId : 1001
State : CLEARED_ACKNOWLEDGED
lastUpdated : 2020-09-30T12:43:11

Severity : CLEARED
Node : N01
eventId : 1001
State : CLEARED_UNACKNOWLEDGED
lastUpdated : 2020-09-30T12:35:33

Severity : MEDIUM
Node : N02
eventId : 1002
State : ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED
lastUpdated : 2020-09-30T12:40:00

Severity : HIGH
Node : N02
eventId : 1002
State : ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED
lastUpdated : 2020-09-30T12:45:00

Total number of Alarm(s): 2
```

Output from the above script:

```
EventID,Node,Severity,State,LastUpdate
1001,N01,CLEARED,CLEARED_UNACKNOWLEDGED,2020-09-30T12:35:33
1002,N02,HIGH,ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED,2020-09-30T12:45:00
```

Expected Output:

```
EventID,Node,Severity,State,LastUpdate
1001,N01,CLEARED,CLEARED_ACKNOWLEDGED,2020-09-30T12:43:11
1002,N02,HIGH,ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED,2020-09-30T12:45:00
```

Here the condition is, if particular `eventId` have latest date in `lastUpdated` field and if `CLEARED` severity exists, then this record needs to be considered/printed. Else if `CLEARED` severity doesn't exists for particular `eventId` then it should consider the one has latest date in `lastUpdated` field.
And if the `lastUpdated` is same for CLEARED/HIGH/MEDIUM/LOW severity, then it should pick the record which has CLEARED severity.

So, for event 1001 we have latest date as `2020-09-30T12:43:11`, but it is picking `2020-09-30T12:35:33` which is wrong. Because its the last record for that particular event.

How can I pick the particular events record based on `lastUpdated` and also satisfying the severity condition mentioned above.

Comment: What is the meaning of this condition: `$row eq $selected{lastUpdated} && $row{Severity} eq 'CLEARED'` ? Also it looks like `$row` is the whole paragraph read by `$row = <DATA>`, but `$selected{lastUpdated}` is a hashref

Comment: @HåkonHægland -- `%row` will contain one set of data. and it will check `lastUpdated` date with against `$selected{lastUpdated}`.

Comment: Is string-wise greater/lesser than `gt`, `lt` really suitable for comparing dates?

Comment: @TLP - Its working as expected. But do you suggest to go with Date comparison using Perl module?

Comment: @vkk05 It might be ok for dates in this rather numerical format. But date math often have pitfalls.

Comment: When you compare `$row gt $selected{lastUpdated}` you are comparing a line of input from the file to a hash value for the key `lastUpdated`. Is this really what you want to do?

Comment: @TLP - yes, that's correct.

Comment: @vkk05 A row in this case is a whole block of text such as: `Severity : HIGH
Node : N01
eventId : 1001
State : ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED
lastUpdated : 2020-09-30T12:30:32` and the hash value will be something like `2020-09-30T12:45:00`. I do not believe those are the two things that you mean to compare.

Comment: @vkk05 I will provide you with a way to store the information in a data structure, and you take a look at that and see if you can figure out what to compare to what, ok.

Comment: Sure @TLP. I would also suggest if you're using Perl module for date comparison, go with core modules. My system has `Perl v5.10.1` with Perl minimal installation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you do not quite understand what you have in your various variables. For example, when you do

```
if $row gt $selected{lastUpdated}
```

You are basically doing this:

```
if "Severity : HIGH
Node : N01
eventId : 1001
State : ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED
lastUpdated : 2020-09-30T12:30:32" gt "2020-09-30T12:45:00";
```

The `$row` variable comes from your readline statement in the while condition:

```
while ( my $row = <DATA> ) {
```

Where it reads a whole paragraph of text from the file (because you are using paragraph mode `$/ = ""`). A paragraph ends with double newlines `\n\n` or end of file.

Your best option is to read the file into memory, and then do your comparisons. This sample code will show you how to organize your data into a suitable Perl data structure. I will leave the logic of finding out how to compare the values to you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %log;
local $/ = "";    # paragraph mode

while (<>) {
    next if /^Total number/;
    my (%data) = split / : |\n/;
    push @{$log{$data{eventId}}}, \%data;
}

print Dumper \%log
```

With your data, this gives me the output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '1001' => [
                      {
                        'eventId' => '1001',
                        'lastUpdated' => '2020-09-30T12:30:32',
                        'State' => 'ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED',
                        'Node' => 'N01',
                        'Severity' => 'HIGH'
                      },
                      {
                        'Severity' => 'HIGH',
                        'Node' => 'N01',
                        'State' => 'ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED',
                        'eventId' => '1001',
                        'lastUpdated' => '2020-09-30T12:35:33'
                      },
                      {
                        'eventId' => '1001',
                        'lastUpdated' => '2020-09-30T12:43:11',
                        'Severity' => 'CLEARED',
                        'State' => 'CLEARED_ACKNOWLEDGED',
                        'Node' => 'N01'
                      },
                      {
                        'Node' => 'N01',
                        'State' => 'CLEARED_UNACKNOWLEDGED',
                        'Severity' => 'CLEARED',
                        'eventId' => '1001',
                        'lastUpdated' => '2020-09-30T12:35:33'
                      }
                    ],
          '1002' => [
                      {
                        'lastUpdated' => '2020-09-30T12:40:00',
                        'eventId' => '1002',
                        'Severity' => 'MEDIUM',
                        'State' => 'ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED',
                        'Node' => 'N02'
                      },
                      {
                        'lastUpdated' => '2020-09-30T12:45:00',
                        'eventId' => '1002',
                        'Node' => 'N02',
                        'State' => 'ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED',
                        'Severity' => 'HIGH'
                      }
                    ]
        };
```

This is a hash where each unique eventId has an array of records attached to it. With this structure, you can easily loop around the various `eventId` values to find the highest/lowest `lastUpdated` or `Severity`. For example you can sort the eventIds based on lastUpdated using `cmp` (string-wise greatness):

```
for my $key (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %log) {
    print "eventId: $key\n";
    for my $record (sort { $a->{lastUpdated} cmp $b->{lastUpdated} } @{ $log{$key} }) {
                       # this will sort the hashes inside the array based on lastUpdated
        print "\t$record->{lastUpdated}";
        if ($record->{Severity} eq 'CLEARED') {
            print "\tCLEARED";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

For the data you provided, this will print

```
eventId: 1001
        2020-09-30T12:30:32
        2020-09-30T12:35:33
        2020-09-30T12:35:33     CLEARED
        2020-09-30T12:43:11     CLEARED
eventId: 1002
        2020-09-30T12:40:00
        2020-09-30T12:45:00
```

Since I am not clear on what your logic is exactly, I will leave those details to you.

Comment: Finally I want only latest record to be printed. i.e., `1001,2020-09-30T12:43:11,CLEARED` and `1002,2020-09-30T12:45:00,HIGH`.

Comment: You can always reverse the sort order by changing place of `$a` and `$b`.

Comment: ok, once I have the latest record by sorting it in reverse order, shall I `last` the loop. So that other record for same eventId won't get printed.

Comment: @vkk05 That would be a good idea. Not sure where you want the CLEARED flag to factor in, though.

Comment: Lets say for 1001 eventId I have CLEARED and HIGH severity at same time (`2020-09-30T12:43:11`). In this case I should pick CLEARED severity one.

Comment: The OP's code is my code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64011173/589924). There were some mistakes cause I was annoyed cause the OP kept changing the question. The answer has been fixed. (I think. I'm on my phone.)

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

local $/ = "\n\n";
my $events = {};

while( <DATA> ) {
    my $hr = {};
    while( /(\w+) *: *(.+)\n/g ) {
        $hr->{$1} = $2;
    }

    if( exists $events->{ $hr->{eventId} } ) {
        if( $events->{ $hr->{eventId} }->{lastUpdated} lt $hr->{lastUpdated} ) {
            $events->{ $hr->{eventId} } = $hr;
        }
    }
    elsif( $hr->{eventId} )  {
        $events->{ $hr->{eventId} } = $hr;
    }

}

print Dumper($events), "\n";
```

Comment: thanks @Miguel Prz. I could see a warning in `if` condition. Can I use `next unless $hr->{eventId};` before the `if`.

Comment: Also what is the meaning of `local $/ = "\n\n";` Is it a paragraph mode?

Comment: No, `= ""` is paragraph mode, a better choice than matching two line feeds (`= "\n\n"`)