# Get a record based on Updated time and Severity

Tags: perl

I have some event data, I need to print only single data with respect to a single event based on the Updated time of the event.

I have all the data saved in the hash of arrays and from there I need to extract a single record from each of the events which have the latest updated time.

Here is the script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data = (
          '1342' => [
                      {
                        'Severity' => 'MEDIUM',
                        'Node' => 'Node002',
                        'State' => 'ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED',
                        'Updated' => '2020-10-01T12:00:00',
                        'eventId' => '1342'
                      },
                      {
                        'Severity' => 'HIGH',
                        'Node' => 'Node002',
                        'Updated' => '2020-10-01T12:05:00',
                        'eventId' => '1342',
                        'State' => 'ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED'
                      }
                    ],
          '1341' => [
                      {
                        'State' => 'ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED',
                        'eventId' => '1341',
                        'Updated' => '2020-10-01T12:10:00',
                        'Node' => 'Node001',
                        'Severity' => 'HIGH'
                      },
                      {
                        'State' => 'ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED',
                        'Updated' => '2020-10-01T12:15:00',
                        'eventId' => '1341',
                        'Severity' => 'HIGH',
                        'Node' => 'Node001'
                      },
                      {
                        'State' => 'CLEARED_ACKNOWLEDGED',
                        'Updated' => '2020-10-01T12:15:00',
                        'eventId' => '1341',
                        'Severity' => 'CLEARED',
                        'Node' => 'Node001'
                      }
                    ]
);

foreach my $id ( sort keys %data ){
    print "Event: $id\n";
    foreach my $record( sort { $b->{Updated} cmp $a->{Updated} } @{ $data{$id} }) {
        print "\t";
        print "$record->{Node},$record->{Severity},$record->{State},$record->{Updated}";
        print "\n";
        last;
    }
}
```

**Current Output:**

```
Event: 1341
        Node001,HIGH,ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED,2020-10-01T12:15:00
Event: 1342
        Node002,HIGH,ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED,2020-10-01T12:05:00
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Event: 1341
        Node001,CLEARED,CLEARED_ACKNOWLEDGED,2020-10-01T12:15:00
Event: 1342
        Node002,HIGH,ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED,2020-10-01T12:05:00
```

If the particular event has the same updated time for different severities, it should pick the record which has CLEARED severity.

In the above case, we can see for `EventID` `1341` there are `CLEARED` and `HIGH` severity exists at the same time i.e., `2020-10-01T12:15:00`.
So, I should pick the `CLEARED` severity record instead of `HIGH` severity. How can I pick that record?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64155295/725418

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over each level in your data structure so  to be able to compare as needed

```
foreach my $ev (sort keys %data) { 
    my $ra = $data{$ev}; 
    
    my $fmt = "%Y-%m-%dT%T";

    # Initialize "best" time and its hashref
    my $hr = $ra->[0];
    my $dt = Time::Piece->strptime($hr->{Updated}, $fmt);
    
    foreach my $idx (1..$#$ra) { 
        my $dt_curr = Time::Piece->strptime(
            $ra->[$idx]{Updated}, $fmt
        );

        if ($dt_curr > $dt) {
            $dt = $dt_curr;
            $hr = $ra->[$idx];
        }
        elsif ($dt_curr == $dt) { 
            if ($ra->[$idx]{Severity} eq 'CLEARED') { 
                $dt = $dt_curr;
                $hr = $ra->[$idx];
            }
        }
    }   
    say "Event: $hr->{eventId}";
    say "\t", join ',', 
        map { $hr->{$_} } qw(Node Severity State Updated);
    # Or rather, as clarified in a comment
    #say join ',' 
    #    map { $hr->{$_} } qw(eventId Node Severity State Updated);
}
```

With the provided `%data`, omitted for readability, this prints expected results.<sup>†</sup>

I assume that there aren't yet deeper levels in the data structure and so I merely copy hashrefs, otherwise they should be cloned (deep-copied).

The shown timestamps (`%Y-%m-%dT%T`) can be directly compared lexicographically as strings (`$dt1 gt $dt2`) but I still used a date-time module since it's then easy to adjust if a different timestamp format ends up being used.

The code can be tweaked for efficiency. (That also depends on data details.)

---

A question came up of how to do it without `Time::Piece` (or any library I take it), as it is unavailable in that install. Please see comments for what I'd like to say about working with such (crippled) tool, but here's a simple way.  (This is also faster.)

```
sub parse_ts {               # add checks
    my ($timestamp) = @_;
    
    # For format year-mon-dayThour:minute:second
    return split /[-T:]/, $timestamp;
}

my ($yr, $mon, $day, $hr, $min, $sec) = parse_ts($timestamp);
```

The `split`'s argument for the separator is a regex. As a char from the *character class* `[-T:]` is matched in the string (tried in the given order) the string is split on it. Their order is as in the timestamp so `split` returns: year, month, day, hour, minute, second.

With such a list for each timestamp we can intelligibly compare their date-times, by comparing components in that order (compare year, then month, ...).

However, with `Time::Local` (confirmed to be installed) you can avoid writing the tedious (and error prone) code to compare components, by obtaining seconds since epoch using `timelocal` and comparing that

```
use Time::Local;
# parse timestamps to get yr, mon, ... for each
my $dt1 = timelocal($sec1, $min1, $hour1, $mday1, $mon1, $yr1);
my $dt2 = ...

if ($dt1 > $dt2) { ... }
```

Altogether, with a rudimentary sanity check

```
sub ts_to_epoch {
    my ($timestamp) = @_;

    # For format year-mon-dayThour:minute:second
    my @dt_parts = split /[-T:]/, $timestamp;
    die "Parsing of '$timestamp' failed" if @dt_parts != 6;

    return timelocal( reverse @dt_parts );
}

my $epoch_1 = ts_to_epoch($timestamp1);
...
```

If you ever need to retrieve a timestamp from those seconds-since-epoch one way with your limited toolset is with `localtime($epoch)`.

---

<sup>†</sup>  The last line of code (commented out) prints in the desired order by listing keys in that order. But if that appears at many places in the code then we'd have hard-coded key-list scattered around; what when another key is added, or renamed?  We'd have to hunt down all those places.

Instead, spell out the order in an ancillary hash

```
# One place in code where the hard-coded order is given
my %sort_by = do {
    my @keys = qw(eventId Node Severity State Updated);
    map { $keys[$_] => $_ } 0..$#keys;
};
```

and now print by fetching the keys using `keys` and then sorting them

```
say join ',', 
    map { $hr->{$_} } 
    sort { $sort_by{$a} <=> $sort_by{$b} } 
    keys %$hr;
```

So `%sort_by` is given at one place in the code (and make it constant!), and printing statements don't use any specific, hard-coded data.

Comment: this produces the result as expected. Here I am using `Perl 5.10` with minimal installation which doesn't have core modules. So is there any possibility/alternative for `Time::Piece` Perl Module which comes with Perl 5.10 minimal installation.

Comment: @vkk05 If you can't use libraries then you'd have to write code to parse the date-time string and compare them piece by piece.  (With timestamps in this question you can compare them as strings, lexicographically, as I noted in the answer.  But by the question in the comment I assume that the format indeed isn't necessarily as shown and that you want to treat it as datetime.  Then you have to write your own code for that If you can't use ready libraries.)

Comment: @vkk05 Not being able to use even core modules is a bit of an impossible predicament.  Tools in a major computing environment are structured and organized, and good chunks of functionality are by design (and often necessarily) in modules/libraries.  If you can't use those then you are working with a crippled tool and you'll have to implement some functionalities yourself. This may be OK (often the case when you seek conveniece of a scripting language in a complied one!), and comparing two dates is simple to do. But good luck with going out on internet or using a database without libraries.

Comment: @vkk05 I don't mean to criticize you or anything such, just saying that you should expect some tough spots if you are working with a restricted set of tools in a language.

Answer (score 1):

A small change in OP's code produces desired result

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my %data = (
          '1342' => [
                      {
                        'Severity' => 'MEDIUM',
                        'Node' => 'Node002',
                        'State' => 'ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED',
                        'Updated' => '2020-10-01T12:00:00',
                        'eventId' => '1342'
                      },
                      {
                        'Severity' => 'HIGH',
                        'Node' => 'Node002',
                        'Updated' => '2020-10-01T12:05:00',
                        'eventId' => '1342',
                        'State' => 'ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED'
                      }
                    ],
          '1341' => [
                      {
                        'State' => 'ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED',
                        'eventId' => '1341',
                        'Updated' => '2020-10-01T12:10:00',
                        'Node' => 'Node001',
                        'Severity' => 'HIGH'
                      },
                      {
                        'State' => 'ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED',
                        'Updated' => '2020-10-01T12:15:00',
                        'eventId' => '1341',
                        'Severity' => 'HIGH',
                        'Node' => 'Node001'
                      },
                      {
                        'State' => 'CLEARED_ACKNOWLEDGED',
                        'Updated' => '2020-10-01T12:15:00',
                        'eventId' => '1341',
                        'Severity' => 'CLEARED',
                        'Node' => 'Node001'
                      }
                    ]
);

foreach my $id ( sort keys %data ){
    print "Event: $id\n";
    my $found;
    for( @{$data{$id}} ) {
        $found = $_ unless defined $found;
        if( $_->{Updated} eq $found->{Updated} ) {
            $found = $_ if $_->{Severity} eq 'CLEARED';
        }
        $found = $_ if $_->{Updated} ge $found->{Updated};
    }
    say "\t" . join ',', $found->@{qw/Node Severity State Updated/};
}
```

Output

```
Event: 1341
        Node001,CLEARED,CLEARED_ACKNOWLEDGED,2020-10-01T12:15:00
Event: 1342
        Node002,HIGH,ACTIVE_UNACKNOWLEDGED,2020-10-01T12:05:00
```

Comment: thanks @Polar Bear. the logic looks simple and interesting, and I am getting the output as expected. But is it okay to use `ge` operator for time comparison?

Comment: @vkk05 your ISO timestamp has the very interesting property of being sortable ASCIbetically. The `YYYY-MM-DD` format is vastly superior to localised formats like `DD.MM.YYYY` or `MM/DD/YYYY` in that it has being in the right order basically built in, like when you look at folders named after dates. The `T` is always the same, and a `HH:MM:SS` string always sorts in the expected way. So yes, you can use a string greater-equal for this. No need to parse.

Comment: @vkk05 -- in this particular case due date format used `ge` operator is applicable. If date format was different then you had to make some manipulation with it to make it __sortable__ without parsing with assistance of some module (you yourself would do simple parsing and rearrange date components).